# Using django web app backend with mobile app on ReactJS

Tags: python, django, reactjs, web, mobile

I have backend of web app by django, include registrations/user profile, 
the ability to add photo(video) file and view them, and list of places with the ability to book them.

Now I need to add the ability to work with a mobile application written in ReactJS.

The problem is that before that I did not work with mobile applications and I do not know what strategy to choose, but the frontend developer did not work with the backend. Can I pass django variables directly to the ReactJS code? Do I need additional technologies or frameworks? I would be grateful if someone shared their experience and described how to do it (preferably the least simple way)

Comment: you will need to use `django-rest-framework`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a REST API. In your case, the best solution would be creating the API with [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

It is a very powerful framework for building APIs. They provide some nice tutorials to get started with it.

After that, you can create the frontend app with React by using API calls.

Comment: @lepiloff if this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the 'check' icon.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it possible pass django variables directly to the ReactJS code?

Comment: Short answer: No!